# javascript validation in asp.net mvc not working for login form

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code I have tried each and everything but I dont Know why client side javascript validations are not working.Please help.

I have enabled javascript in view web.config and main web.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

  </appSettings>
```

Model class
tblUser.cs

```
namespace MvcWebApplication.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class tblUser
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Email Id")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(18,ErrorMessage="The password must be atleast 6 characters long",MinimumLength=6)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using layout page for my view where i have mention necessary script file
_LoginLayout.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         @RenderBody();
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my view
Index.cshtml

```
@model MvcWebApplication.Models.tblUser

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LoginLayout.cshtml";
}



<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="formcenter">
        <div id="loginTitle">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            //To handle Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attcks.
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <table class="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(user => user.Email)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Email)</td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(user => user.Email)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowspace">
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(pass => pass.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="rowspace">

                    <td colspan="3" id="button">
                        <input type="button" value="Log In" /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form does not have a submit button

Comment: Thank you Stephen Muecke. My problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the sources of scripts are ok

>

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="~/anything/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/anything/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="~/anything/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/css/Login.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
         @RenderBody();
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```